# how to use redux middleware but to maintain the application state in other ways

Tags: javascript, redux

The state of my application is not suitable for the normal redux approach. So I can't use the state container maintained by the redux. But I want to use the ecosystem of the middlewares of redux. So I came up with an idea. I can do the custom actions in the reduce function but without return a valid state. Like this:

```
function reduce(action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'type0':
      doSomeThingToMaintainMyState()
    ...
  }
  return 
}
```

I want to know If this is a good way for my situation?  Or is there exist any powerful frameworks that can use a middleware system like redux but without a state container?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do here? Reducer needs to be a pure function and always return state. If your need is to run some "side effect" after action is dispatched e.g. call rest api, then you can use async actions such as redux-thunk or redux-saga middlewares.

Comment: So the more acceptable way is I just do nothing in reduce function. but do everything in middleware?@JaniSiivola

Comment: I’m still don’t quite understand what is your question. What do you mean by “The state of my application is not suitable for the normal redux approach”? Could you be more specific of your problem?

In the the reducer you always return a new state that represents the state of your application after some action has happened. It’s possible to execute side effects e.g. async actions before reducer but eventually you need to execute your reducer as well and return a state.

Comment: In redux, I need to gather all state data together. And that's the pure data. I mean no method bound. But my application's state is structured in a class. and they had a loop referenced by nature. @JaniSiivola